# При попытке установить пакет в Ubuntu 18.04 ругается на недоустановленный пакет, можно ли как-то убрать этот пакет из установки?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, apt, dpkg

Устанавливаю пакет `docker-ce`:

```
sudo apt install -f docker-ce
```

Менеджер пакетов пытается доустановить пакет `grub-pc` и у него возникает ошибка:

> mv: cannot move '/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' to '/boot/grub/grub.cfg': Permission denied.

Разблокировать `grub.cfg` нельзя никак (используется особая система защиты таких файлов на уровне биоса (биос особый)). Можно ли как-то пропустить установку этого `grub-pc` — мне он сейчас вообще не требуется. Например, пометить его так, что он уже сконфигурирован?

```
user@ubuntu18:/var/www/home-call$ sudo apt install -f docker-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
docker-ce is already the newest version (5:20.10.21~3-0~ubuntu-bionic).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up docker-ce (5:20.10.21~3-0~ubuntu-bionic) ...
A dependency job for docker.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "restart" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com

Nov 29 09:21:20 ubuntu18 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 29 09:21:20 ubuntu18 systemd[1]: docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Nov 29 09:23:00 ubuntu18 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 29 09:23:00 ubuntu18 systemd[1]: docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Nov 30 07:29:48 ubuntu18 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 30 07:29:48 ubuntu18 systemd[1]: docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Nov 30 07:31:56 ubuntu18 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 30 07:31:56 ubuntu18 systemd[1]: docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Nov 30 07:36:25 ubuntu18 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 30 07:36:25 ubuntu18 systemd[1]: docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up grub-pc (2.02-2ubuntu8.23) ...
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.86
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.19.86
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-197-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-197-generic
mv: cannot move '/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' to '/boot/grub/grub.cfg': Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up friendly-recovery (0.2.38ubuntu1.2) ...
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.86
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.19.86
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-197-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-197-generic
mv: cannot move '/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' to '/boot/grub/grub.cfg': Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package friendly-recovery (--configure):
 installed friendly-recovery package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
 grub-pc
 friendly-recovery
```

Answer (score 3):

Создай пустой пакет. Установи вместо оригинального и тогда апт не будет просить о нём.

https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/HackingDependencies и немного подробнее https://debian-handbook.info/browse/ru-RU/stable/sect.building-first-package.html